# Does xvalue/prvalue category really matter?

Tags: c++11, xvalue

The only way to create xvalue is use static_cast< T&& > conversion.
Yes, [according to standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) there are also three other situation but all of them require another xvalue. So, for simplicity, I will assume that is only way for now.

We need pass something to static_cast. Let's call it «gizmo».
No matter what exactly is gizmo (lvalue or rvalue), result of static_cast would be rvalue reference to exactly same thing (I mean that it would not produce any temporary object). Value category of result would be either prvalue or xvalue (for objects). Let us consider the second case.

I understand that xvalue is far better for objects than prvalue cause it has dynamic type; but strange thing is that I don't know any action with «gizmo» whose produce prvalue that contain reference to same thing: it is look like all action that convert «gizmo» to prvalue (like static_cast< T > or pass to function with non-reference result) would create temporary object (with call copy constructor and so on).

Summarize, if we have value of object type we can either:

1. produce xvalue with reference to that value

or

2. produce prvalue with reference to temporary object (probably copy of value)*

Maybe really important thing is where rvalue reference actually refers to (same thing or copy) rather than it xvalue/prvalue category?
If so we might think that static_cast< T&& > just only way to save reference to same thing and don't care anymore about xvalue/prvalue. Is not it?

---

- Of course if value is already prvalue we are not obliged to do something to get prvalue but in this case dynamic type can't be lost. So, there is no difference with xvalue again.

Comment: I can't tell what your actual question is.  Are you looking for a scenario in which xvalue and prvalue behave differently?

Comment: I am trying to write snippet where the only reason of different behavior was different value category (xvalue/prvalue). But when I try convert something to prvalue it actually produce temporary object. It is look like this side effect is main reason of difference behavior.

Comment: There are my tries: https://ideone.com/3UrjTK

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: I read this question at least half a dozen times, and I still can't figure out what question is actually being asked.

Comment: @T.C. I *suppose* he's probably arguing on the necessity itself of introducing two categories for prvalue and xvalue.. but I'm not so sure either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xvalue` and `prvalue` matters when using `decltype` deduction rules, for example. What [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) says:

- a) if the value category of expression is `xvalue`, then `decltype` yields `T&&`;
- b) if the value category of expression is `lvalue`, then `decltype` yields `T&`;
- c) if the value category of expression is `prvalue`, then `decltype` yields `T`.

In this way, the compiler has a better hint of what kind of expression is coming. And of course, it's just important in a semantic sense of dealing with expressions.

Example:

```
struct A {};
int main() {
    decltype(auto) a1 = A(); //prvalue, type of a1 is A
    decltype(auto) a2 = std::move(A()); //xvalue, type of a2 is A&&
}
```

Using `auto` in this example, both `a1` and `a2` would get `A` as type.